# Global Search - Not matches found message

Tags: externalid, global-search

I'm trying to search a record using a global search putting part of the content, but the results show a message: "No matches found".

If I put all the content, the global search show me the record. See the screenshots.

**Search with all the content**
[image: All the content]

**Search with part of content**
[image: Part of content]

Points to consider:

- I created a tab to the object;
- The field is already on the search results page
- The field is an external ID
- The FLS is configured

Comment: You have a trailing wildcard (`222964*`) instead of a leading wildcard (`*222964`). Try moving the wildcard character to the beginning.

Comment: Hi Adrian,
I tried, but doesn't work too.

Comment: @AdrianLarson that will not work, I have found this undocumented trick `'*222964'`, use of single quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intended result to show `10010222964` then you have to search with

`'*222964'` (*Please mind the single quote at the beginning and at the end*)

> Though I didn't find this trick in the  [Wildcards and operators for search](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230635&language=en_US&type=1) documentation. But it works for me!
>
> By the way, `*` asterisk characters best to find items that match zero or more characters at the middle or end of your query. It doesn't work at the beginning.

Currently, you are searching `222964*` where system is searching for anything starts with `222964`.

Comment: Hello Santanu,
I tried searching using the wildcard like you said, but doesn't work.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: copy and paste exactly this search phrase:    '*0222964'

Comment: Works like a charm!!! I did not knew that trick
Thanks a lot Santanu

Comment: this is `undocumented` trick